# What does choosing good or evil when you escape do?

Tags: diehard-dungeon

After you escape the dungeon you are offered a choice between good and evil. What does this choice do? Are there any mechanical differences between choosing them? Are there any benefits to choosing one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, all it does is place your name over the 'good' or 'evil' champions that appear in the dungeon during champion mode.

When you choose good, your name can appear on a 'good' (blue) champion. When you choose evil, your name can appear on a 'evil' (red) champion.